# How do we deal with situations where nobody who has the problem, knows proper terminology (and it's an actual source of ambiguity)?

Tags: discussion

I'm sick and tired of trying to look up canonicals for problems in combinatorics, because every time I try I get flooded with Q&A for the wrong question.

The root of the problem is that basically everyone who has some specific problem in combinatorics believes that the word "combinations" is the correct way to describe what they want. In reality, "combinations" has a specific meaning, corresponding to some, but not all of these problems. It is especially common for people to use the term "combinations" when they really want a Cartesian product.

This leads to a host of unclear questions such as [How can I get pairs of values, where the first is taken from one list and the second from another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499327), where I have inferred (along with the originally accepted answer), based on the code example, that it's yet another Cartesian product question. The original title was totally useless ("Is there python way to generate pairs?"), but this has still somehow managed to get 84k views. The problem is that a lot of these sorts of questions will explicitly - in titles, code samples, etc. say "combinations" where they shouldn't, and this *also* worsens the search results for people who *actually do* want to generate combinations.<sup>1</sup>

Worse yet, even if we actually had a canonical for "what are all these combinatorics tools in the `itertools` standard library? What is the difference between `combinations`, `permutations`, `combinations_with_replacement` and `product`<sup>2</sup>?" - we can't really direct people there, because they *don't actually have that question*, because they *lack awareness* of the existence of the underlying combinatorics questions. They just want a loop that iterates over whatever pattern of values, which they think are called "combinations" (because that would be a perfectly ordinary way to use that word in day-to-day English).

Even extremely popular reference canonicals in this are getting it completely wrong. For example, [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864) is asking about power sets, but the *accepted answer* simply describes combinations - because that's how it was phrased.

In specific: What should the ideal set of canonical questions look like to cover the problem space of basic combinatorics in Python?

More generally: how can we improve search results for something where the searchers don't actually know what to search for, and are also actively sabotaging each other with their inaccurate descriptions?

<sup>1</sup> It also happens sometimes that people talk about "all the combinations", when what they really mean is a *power set*. As it happens, that actually *is* equivalent to a union of all combinations of all lengths. Related to that, the rows of [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) sum to powers of 2.

<sup>2</sup> As it happens, a Cartesian product is actually equivalent to "permutations with replacement" - but the latter is a strange and awkward way of thinking about the issue.

Comment: Ideally, a canonical would contain a title and opening paragraph/sentence that is likely to match the searches people unfamiliar with the topic would be making, regardless of what the "proper terminology" is. this is why it's generally better for canonicals to happen organically rather than experts creating both the question and answer.

Comment: @KevinB the problem is, if we did it that way, **the canonicals for multiple at-most-tangentially-related questions would have identical titles**. There is also the question of the burden upon duplicate closers: how on earth are they supposed to find the right one?

Comment: well, no, because SO doesn't allow identical titles.

Comment: Functionally identical. Not distinguishable. Polluting search results.

Comment: i mean, that's the normal state of affairs here. Titles are written by people who have no idea what they're looking for, which is naturally going to match the search terms people with the problem are using. That it makes it near impossible for experts to be able to find them so that we can put questions into neat little buckets isn't really the purpose

Comment: "There is also the question of the burden upon duplicate closers: how on earth are they supposed to find the right one?" - you make a list.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I already have over a thousand questions in my saves, and searching them is often difficult - compounded by the fact that the site search trips up on a lot of easy problems, and external search has no access to my saves list (and I certainly wouldn't want it to have that access).

Comment: So make a list in markdown and post it on GitHub. Or GitLab. Or on any number of other free or paid closed-source/open-source hosting solutions. There are more ways to make public lists than the amount of time (in seconds) collectively spent on saying Stack's search is trash. I have one for some of the regular dupes I run into

Comment: I was about to ask how you integrate that into your workflow, and then I realized: this feels like work, and I'm not getting paid for it. I feel like taking another hiatus.

Comment: *"I already have over a thousand questions in my saves, and searching them is often difficult"* ... do you just save a list of links? You already know that the original titles are often bad and/or misleading. Use your own words and knowledge to properly describe those links so you'll have an easier time finding links you're looking for.

Comment: "I was about to ask how you integrate that into your workflow" - I open the tab. If I recognise a dupe I don't know the title of off the top of my head, I go to the tab, look at the convenient table of contents, click the relevant category, read until I find the correct link (annotated with keywords I wrote), copy the link, paste the link, and close the question. It isn't hard. "this feels like work, and I'm not getting paid for it." - spoiler alert; it already _is_ work. When you close questions, or do any other moderation action, you do work that some companies with equivalent services

Comment: pay for, for free. That's what volunteering is. If you don't feel it's worth your time (anymore), don't do it. No one's forcing you, and because you aren't an employee, you don't have to give notice. You can just stop for any reason and any duration

Comment: It is work, but you also learn a lot in the process. This may become very useful years down the line. As an example, the ability to *quickly* and efficiently built your own ad hoc tools.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel if the issue that hampers your workflow is keeping track of which canonicals answer which kind of question, then I’d like to recommend the userscript I wrote (you’ll find it in my StackApps account). I wrote it to solve that exact issue. I’m posting this comment specifically in response to *” I already have over a thousand questions in my saves, and searching them is often difficult”*

Comment: *"I feel like taking another hiatus"* - sounds like a plan to me, you do what you have to do so you do not burn out. Because essentially you're becoming upset over what is pretty much just the usual influx of low quality questions caused by people not being well-informed. It's not going to stop. Ever. If I want to actually answer something in my own arena, I probably have to walk circles around it at least 10 times wading through nothing but duplicate questions. There is nothing to be done about it.